# GWT Textbox Encoding and RPC

Tags: java, gwt, encoding

Let's say I have a TextBox and the user puts some data in it. I then send the data over RPC, with something like this (synchronous version of interface)

```
public void submitText(String userData) {
  dao.saveText(userData);
}
```

My questions are:

- What is the encoding of the userData? This is a trick question, since Strings in java are stored in UTF-16, what I want to know is if my text box sends funny characters like **ã** or **Í** or **€**, and if I later feed that chars to a xml document, what should be the xml encoding?
- Do I need to care about encoding when submitting data this way? Or GWT assures me that the chars within the userData are properly converted from the http request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 issues:

1. The "Serialization" or "Marshalling" of data built into RPC handles binary conversions such as machine byte order differences.
2. the "xml document" you refer to should use ["UTF-16" encoding](http://www.w3schools.com/XML/xml_encoding.asp) if you plan on writing Java Strings as "binary characters" to it.
3. another approach is to use 8-bit encoding and translate all the 16-bit characters to markup as in non-breaking-space "

> `&nbsp;`

"